# VS Code starts python processes every time I jump from an environment to another and everyone of them drains about 100% of CPU

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, process

VS Code starts python/python3 (together with "code helper renderer" processes) processes every time I jump from an environment to another and everyone of them drains about 100% of CPU.

This happens without me running or even writing any code.

I've tried to delete the environments, delete some vscode extensions i might have installed, delete some python version but with zero luck.

Any clue on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After I tried disabling / enabling every single vscode extension it turned out that was the python extension causing that problem.
I fixed it installing an older version (gen 2021) and everything seems to be working just fine.

I thought this might come useful to somebody.